# In which Unit do I find TidHeaderList?

Tags: delphi, indy10, delphi-10.3-rio

I need to use TidHeaderList in my deviation of TidHTTP but cant find the unit it is included in.

Any hints?

Comment: For future reference, if you use the IDE's *Search->Find in Files* and point it to the Indy directories and tell it to include subfolders, it can answer these sorts of question in less time than it took you to post this question here. It also works with the VCL and FMX source folders or any other folders that contain Delphi source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of Indy's classes are implemented in their own units.  A simple grep of Indy's source code (or a review of [Indy's documentation](https://www.indyproject.org/documentation/)) would have shown you that `TIdHeaderList` is in the **`IdHeaderList.pas`** unit (which is in the `uses` clause of the `interface` section of the `IdHTTP.pas` unit).